# Read buffer as string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read a buffer as string using node.js 
i am using api which is return buffer when i console buffer it looks like

```
<Buffer 00 05 02 00 00 00 00 00 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 31 30 36 35 37 30 30 31 3534 35 37 38 34 20 01 c6 03 b4 03 cc 0c 04 21 de 01 3b b0 a1 ff 8a 48 80 01 50 06 ...>
```

My code is:-

```
server.on("message", function (buffer){
   console.log(buffer);//this is buffer
   console.log(buffer.toString());
});
```

when I try to convert into string it give the following output:-

`♣☻           010657001545784 ☺?♥?♥?♀♦!?☺;????H?☺P♠?☻.?  ?♠`;

I have also try to conver it `utf-8` but no luck.
can anyone tell me which is this format and how I can get proper string from this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what kind of data are you expecting to get from the buffer? where does it originate from?

Comment: According to the [ASCII Table](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/1280px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png) the displayed buffer's values are correct with theses values. @andrew +1

Comment: @Andrew its coming from service I don't have its code.it has some information like ip address,name etc. as string seprate by comma.

Comment: I see, do you have any idea what the Ip address inside the buffer you posted may be? an Ip address is only 4 bytes.

Comment: @Andrew may be `10.104.228.178`

Comment: That would be `0a 68 e4 b2` which isn't in your string, but maybe its encoded somehow